# Perl Script Portability and Future Proofing

Tags: perl, scripting, portability, future-proof

Due to pressure from outside our group, we have to port over one hundred Perl scripts from Sparc to x86. This means changing dozens of shebang lines from `#!/home/Perl/bin/perl -w` to something else, which is a real pain. What is good way to do this (I can't find anything on [Lycos](http://search.lycos.com/?tab=web&query=Port+Perl+Scripts+from+Sparc+to+x86))?

Also what happens when we're forced to move from x86 to something else (like Cray, I suppose)? Is there some way to "future-proof"?

Comment: @Ether - They do. IIRC the last owner was some Korean company. They have both HotBot aggregate search (their own+MSN+ask.com results) and the proprietary LyGO "visual search" engine - which sounds a bit cool BUT uses the same crappy way outdated old Lycos search index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the shebang lines *en masse* ain't so bad:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find;

sub usage { "Usage: $0 dir ..\n" }

my @todo;
sub has_perl_shebang {
  return unless -f;
  open my $fh, "<", $_ or warn "$0: open $File::Find::name: $!", return;
  push @todo => $File::Find::name
    if (scalar(<$fh>) || "") =~ /\A#!.*\bperl/i;
}

die usage unless @ARGV;
find \&has_perl_shebang => @ARGV;

local($^I,@ARGV) = ("",@todo);
while (<>) {
  s[ ^ (\#!.*) $ ][#! /usr/bin/env perl]x
    if $. == 1;
  print;
}
continue {
  close ARGV if eof;
}
```

Depending on what you have, the `s///` may need to be a little smarter to handle switches such as `-T` that must be on the shebang line.

Add a dry-run option with a few changes, plus an interesting use of [`redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html):

```
my $dryrun;
{
  die usage unless @ARGV;
  $dryrun = shift @ARGV, redo if $ARGV[0] eq "-n";
}

find \&has_perl_shebang => @ARGV;
if ($dryrun) {
  warn "$0: $_\n" for @todo;
  exit 1;
}
```

Comment: Very nice!

Do I run this on Sparc or X86? I guess X86 will be faster.

Comment: @Ariel Thanks! You'd run this on the x86 (destination) side because it fixes the shebang lines in-place.

Answer (score 11):

This is one reason many people advocate using [`#!/usr/bin/env perl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Portability) instead of `#!/usr/bin/perl`:

Comment: How does this make my scripts portable?

Comment: They will run on whichever "perl" executable the system finds, via `/usr/bin/env`...

Comment: @Ariel: More specifically, using `#!/usr/bin/env perl` will cause the program to be run using the first `perl` binary found in the controlling user's `PATH`. Note that if, by "x86" you mean "Windows", this isn't relevant anyhow, since Windows goes by the file extension and completely ignores the `#!` line.

Comment: I use this script for Perl shebang headers:
http://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/bin/envperl

Answer (score 5):

Perl is cross-platform. Unless your code makes use of `XS` compiled code or system-specific paths, facilities, etc., you should be fine.

You have two options:

1. Don't use shebang lines (`perl yourscript.pl`).
2. `find . -name '*pl' | xargs sed 's/#!\/home\/Perl\/bin\/perl -w/#!\/usr\/bin\/env perl/`

In any case, the shebang line has nothing to do with the hardware platform you're running, and all with the shell you're running on.

Comment: Sorry. I should have state my shell. I am using `tcsh` is this my problem?

Comment: Nope, `tcsh` supports shebang lines. If your systems have `env` installed, you just need to change your scripts with option 2, above.

Comment: I cannot guarantee that the systems running our scripts have `env` installed.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative (might be simpler though I would hesitate to say "better") is, of course, to soft-link `/home/Perl/bin/perl` to wherever actual Perl binary on the new systems will be... it's only feasible if you have efficient bulk system admin tools which most normal companies should.

Comment: What is "efficient bulk system admin tools"? I don't think we have that.

Comment: Something that'd allow you to create such a symlink on every single existing and new x86 server without doing it individually server-by-server (unless of course you only have 2-3 servers in which case it's feasible to do it by hand)